# SetDirectory has problems when path is long and contains too many "_"

Tags: files-and-directories

The following example code does not work (error:  "Cannot set current directory ...").
I am running Mathematica 10.2.0.0 on Windows 10.

```
In[1]:= dirArray = {
   "F:\\dlr\\OM_Laser_Focus\\X-Axis\\super_35_colors_crop_x_200_1100_y_500_677\\",
   "F:\\dlr\\OM_Laser_Focus\\X-Axis\\super_70_colors_crop_x_200_1100_y_500_677\\"
   };

nDirArray = Length[dirArray];

Table[
 dir = dirArray[[n]];
 SetDirectory[dir];

 Table[
  k = 1 (*do something*), {i, 1, 10}
  ];

 , {n, 1, nDirArray}
 ]

During evaluation of In[1]:= SetDirectory::cdir: Cannot set current directory to F:\dlr\OM_Laser_Focus\X-Axis\super_70_colors_crop_x_200_1100_y_500_677\.

Out[3]= {Null, Null}
```

When I replace `dirArray` to:

```
dirArray = {
  "F:\\dlr\\OM_Laser_Focus\\X-Axis\\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01\\",
  "F:\\dlr\\OM_Laser_Focus\\X-Axis\\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz02\\"
}
```

then everything is fine.

What might be the reason?

Comment: see what `FileType /@ dirArray` does.

Comment: It gives: {Directory, Directory} ... is ok ...

Comment: `SetDirectory["F:\\dlr\\OM_Laser_Focus\\X-Axis\\super_35_colors_crop_x_\
200_1100_y_500_677\\"]` works on my system. Windows 7.

Comment: Yes, if you do it isolated as a one line command, but not in the Table environment ... as in my dummy example ... please copy the code above and run it when you created the directories ... thanks

Comment: Is F a network or local drive?

Comment: a local drive ...

Comment: I had to use `G:` as I didn't have a  `F:` drive. Other than that I copied your `dirArray` and code. I modified to print the directory. This command `Table[
 dir = dirArray[[n]];
 SetDirectory[dir];
 Print[Directory[]];
 Table[k = 1 (*do something*), {i, 1, 10}];,
 {n, 1, nDirArray}
 ]` works fine on my system with Mathematica 10.2. It correctly prints the directory.

Comment: great, may be then it has  to do with win10

Comment: @mrz try turning the table into a for loop to avoid concurrent evaluations

Comment: Always better to use `FileNameJoin` than to attempt to specify the full path name  with a string containing escaped back-slashes.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 64bit, Mma 10.2

[`SetDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDirectory.html) has no problem reaching paths up to 250 characters (maximum allowed by the OS) inside [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html). What fails in my test is the creation of the directory.

```
SetDirectory["H:\\"]

Table[
 With[{dir = StringJoin@RandomChoice[{"a", "b", "c", "_"}, 10]},
  CreateDirectory[dir];
  {j, SetDirectory[dir]}
  ],
 {j, 25}]
```

> ```
> {{1,H:\a_cbab__ab},{2,H:\a_cbab__ab\abcacc_cbc},
>  {3,H:\a_cbab__ab\abcacc_cbc\ababbcbcbc},<<20>>,{24,$Failed},{25,$Failed}}
> ```

tested with directory names up to 50 characters, 25% characters were "_".

You need to check if the directory exists using [`DirectoryQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirectoryQ.html). The error you are seeing suggest the directory doesn't exist

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The crazy thing is: when I set the same directory with the many "_" outside of the Table environment ist works fine. The directories are existing. 
E.g.  dir = dirArray[[1]]; SetDirectory[dir]; This works. But as soon it is used in the Table environment with dirArray[[n]] it's not working. 
 Jack Lavigne tried the same with Win7 and in his case it works. I also asked Wolfram and they will answer in 3 days ...